# Segmentation fault when using dlclose(...) on android platform

Tags: android, c++, linux, android-ndk

I have some problems when using the dynamic loading API (`<dlfcn.h>`: `dlopen()`, `dlclose()`, etc) on Android.
I'm using NDK standalone toolchain (version 8) to compile the applications and libraries.
The Android version is 2.2.1 Froyo.

Here is the source code of the simple shared library.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int iii = 0;
int *ptr = NULL;

__attribute__((constructor))
static void init()
{
    iii = 653;
}

__attribute__((destructor))
static void cleanup()
{
}

int aaa(int i)
{
    printf("aaa %d\n", iii);
}
```

Here is the program source code which uses the mentioned library.

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    void *handle;
    typedef int (*func)(int);
    func bbb;

    printf("start...\n");

    handle = dlopen("/data/testt/test.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!handle)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    bbb = (func)dlsym(handle, "aaa");
    if (bbb == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    bbb(1);

    dlclose(handle);
    printf("exit...\n");

    return 0;
}
```

With these sources everything is working fine, but ***when I try to use some STL functions or classes, the program crashes with a segmentation fault***, when the `main()` function exits, for example when using this source code for the shared library.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int iii = 0;
int *ptr = NULL;

__attribute__((constructor))
static void init()
{
    iii = 653;
}

__attribute__((destructor))
static void cleanup()
{
}

int aaa(int i)
{
    cout << iii << endl;
}
```

With this code, the program crashes with segmentation fault after or the during `main()` function exit.
I have tried couple of tests and found the following results.

1. Without using of STL everything is working fine.
2. When use STL and do not call `dlclose()` at the end, everything is working fine.
3. I tried to compile with various compilation flags like `-fno-use-cxa-atexit` or `-fuse-cxa-atexit`, the result is the same.

What is wrong in my code that uses the STL?

Comment: +1 Good Formatted Question ;)

Comment: Is the STL header in the header of so file? Could you take it just to the cpp file? (So STL won't be in interface.) Are the definition and declaration are separated?

Comment: I guess you are talking about the aaa(...) function, if yes, then the declaration and definition are in different files. The definition header file is `#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
int aaa(int i);`

Comment: Is your main program also C++, or have you compiled it as C ?

Comment: Both, program and library are compiled with C++ compiler.

Comment: Have you found any solution for this issue??

Comment: The solution is provided in the last answer.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like I found the reason of the bug. I have tried another example with the following source files:
Here is the source code of the simple class:
myclass.h

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();
    void Set();
    void Show();
private:
    int *pArray;
};
```

myclass.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "myclass.h"

MyClass::MyClass()
{
    pArray = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
}

MyClass::~MyClass()
{
    free(pArray);
    pArray = NULL;
}

void MyClass::Set()
{
    if (pArray != NULL)
    {
        pArray[0] = 0;
        pArray[1] = 1;
        pArray[2] = 2;
        pArray[3] = 3;
        pArray[4] = 4;
    }
}

void MyClass::Show()
{
    if (pArray != NULL)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            printf("pArray[%d] = %d\n", i, pArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see from the code I did not used any STL related stuff.
Here is the source files of the functions library exports.
func.h

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int SetBabe(int);
int ShowBabe(int);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

func.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "myclass.h"
#include "func.h"

MyClass cls;

__attribute__((constructor))
static void init()
{

}

__attribute__((destructor))
static void cleanup()
{

}

int SetBabe(int i)
{
    cls.Set();
    return i;
}

int ShowBabe(int i)
{
    cls.Show();
    return i;
}
```

And finally this is the source code of the programm that uses the library.
main.cpp

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "../simple_lib/func.h"

int main()
{
    void *handle;
    typedef int (*func)(int);
    func bbb;

    printf("start...\n");

    handle = dlopen("/data/testt/test.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!handle)
    {
        printf("%s\n", dlerror());
        return 0;
    }

    bbb = (func)dlsym(handle, "SetBabe");
    if (bbb == NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", dlerror());
        return 0;
    }
    bbb(1);

    bbb = (func)dlsym(handle, "ShowBabe");
    if (bbb == NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", dlerror());
        return 0;
    }
    bbb(1);

    dlclose(handle);
    printf("exit...\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Again as you can see the program using the library also does not using any STL related stuff, but after run of the program I got the same segmentation fault during `main(...)` function exit. So the issue is not connected to STL itself, and it is hidden in some other place. Then after some long research I found the bug.
Normally the `destructors` of static C++ variables are called immediately before `main(...)` function exit, if they are defined in main program, or if they are defined in some library and you are using it, then the destructors should be called immediately before `dlclose(...)`.
On Android OS **all** destructors(defined in main program or in some library you are using) of static C++ variables are called during `main(...)` function exit. So what happens in our case? We have *cls* static C++ variable defined in library we are using. Then immediately before `main(...)` function exit we call `dlclose(...)` function, as a result library closed and *cls* becomes non valid. But the pointer of *cls* is stored somewhere and it's destructor should be called during `main(...)` function exit, and because at the time of call it is already invalid, we get segmentation fault. So the solution is to not call `dlclose(...)` and everything should be fine. Unfortunately with this solution we cannot use ***attribute**((destructor))* for deinitializing of something we want to deinitialize, because it is called as a result of `dlclose(...)` call.

Comment: There have been numerous fixes to destructor handling in Android's libc over time, so the exact behavior will likely depend on the specific version of Android you're using.  I recommend filing a bug on b.android.com, with the sample code, explaining what behavior you're seeing and what you're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

I have a general aversion to calling `dlclose()`.  The problem is that you must ensure that nothing will try to execute code in the shared library after it has been unmapped, or you will get a segmentation fault.

The most common way to fail is to create an object whose **destructor** is defined in or calls code defined in the shared library.  If the object still exists after `dlclose()`, your app will crash when the object is deleted.

If you look at logcat you should see a debuggerd stack trace.  If you can decode that with the arm-eabi-addr2line tool you should be able to determine if it's in a destructor, and if so, for what class.  Alternatively, take the crash address, strip off the high 12 bits, and use that as an offset into the library that was `dlclose()`d and try to figure out what code lives at that address.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same headache on Linux. A work-around that fixes my segfault is to put these lines in the same file as main(), so that dlclose() is called after main returns:

```
static void* handle = 0;
void myDLClose(void) __attribute__ ((destructor));
void myDLClose(void)
{
    dlclose(handle);
}

int main()
{
    handle = dlopen(...);
    /* ... real work ... */
    return 0;
}
```

The root cause of dlclose-induced segfault may be that a particular implementation of dlclose() does not clean up the global variables inside the shared object.

Answer (score -1):

You need to compile with `-fpic` as a compiler flag for the application that is using `dlopen()` and `dlclose()`.  You should also try error handling via `dlerror()` and perhaps checking if the assignment of your function pointer is valid, even if it's not NULL the function pointer could be pointing to something invalid from the initialization, `dlsym()` is not guaranteed to return NULL on android if it cannot find a symbol. Refer to the android documentation opposed to the posix compliant stuff, not everything is posix compliant on android.

Answer (score -2):

You should use extern "C" to declare you function aaa()

Comment: It is done in the appropriate header file, I did not add the contents of that file in the question.