# Should i do malloc() before using dlopen()?

Tags: c++, c, malloc, dlopen

Below shown is the code snippet i am using. Should I allocate space using malloc before doing dlopen?

```
void* pvHandle = NULL;

/* Dynamically loading library */
pvHandle = dlopen ("libame.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL);       
if (!pvHandle)
    {
        pszError = dlerror();
        cout << "Error : " << pszError;
    }
```

Please help me clear this doubt. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What do you want to allocate specifically? I don't get your question.

Comment: Which part of which documentation lead you to believe that you should allocate anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `dlopen` returns an opaque handle to the library, you do not need to allocate any memory yourself.

Comment: So what will happen if i am not using dlclose() ? It shouldnt lead to any memory leak. rite?

Comment: You could leak memory, file handles, whatever. You should call `dlclose`.

Comment: dlclose() leading to segfault on exit. Please check this link : "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450828/segmentation-fault-when-using-dlclose-on-android-platform" . I am also facing same issue. As per this link it says we can avoid calling dlclose(). Any other suggestion appreciated.

Comment: @user2599593 If you are encountering platform issues, you can probably get away with omitting the call, so long as you document the issue.